# How to add dynamic keys with nested level from the array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to create new object on the basis of path array. It will be dynamic. I tried with reduce but it is not giving correct result.

```
const obj = {
  "e": [{
      "name": "moviename",
      "path": ["a"]

    },
    {
      "name": "hero",
      "path": ["a", "b"]
    },
    {
        "name": "desc",
      "path": ["c"]
    },
    {
        "name": "udf",
      "path": []
    }
  ]
}
```

// this is what i want this object to be created programatically.  after parsing above obj.

```
const output = {
  "a": {
    "moviename": "",
    "b": {
      "hero": ""
    }
  },
  "c" : {
    "desc": ""
  },
  "udf": ""
}

const payload = {};
obj.e.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.path.length === 0) {
    payload = {
      ...payload,
      [item.name]: ''
    };
  } else {
    item.path.reduce((o, s, index) => {
      if ((index + 1) === item.path.length) {
        return o[s] = {
          [item.name]: ''
        };
      }
      return o[s] = {};
    }, payload);
  }
});

console.log(payload);
```

Comment: Reduce could be an option here. You should probably share your attempt to see if others can help you find your mistake...

Comment: @trincot shared code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple `for` loops -- `reduce` would also work (see further down), but I think the overhead of a callback is not worth it:

```js
function convert(arr) {
    const output = {};
    for (const {name, path} of arr) {
        let node = output;
        for (let prop of path) {
            node = (node[prop] ??= {});
        }
        node[name] = "";
    }
    return output;
}

const obj = {"e": [{"name": "moviename","path": ["a"]},{"name": "hero","path": ["a", "b"]},{"name": "desc","path": ["c"]},{"name": "udf","path": []}]};

console.log(convert(obj.e));
```

### With `reduce`:

Using `reduce` it would translate to this:

```js
function convert(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((output, {name, path}) => {
        let node = output;
        for (let prop of path) {
            node = (node[prop] ??= {});
        }
        node[name] = "";
        return output;
    }, {});
}

const obj = {"e": [{"name": "moviename","path": ["a"]},{"name": "hero","path": ["a", "b"]},{"name": "desc","path": ["c"]},{"name": "udf","path": []}]};

console.log(convert(obj.e));
```

### With double `reduce`:

If the inner loop is also done through `reduce`, then:

```js
function convert(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((output, {name, path}) => {
        path.reduce((node, prop) => node[prop] ??= {}, output)[name] = "";
        return output;
    }, {});
}


const obj = {"e": [{"name": "moviename","path": ["a"]},{"name": "hero","path": ["a", "b"]},{"name": "desc","path": ["c"]},{"name": "udf","path": []}]};

console.log(convert(obj.e));
```

### The logical nullish assignment operator

If your environment has no support for [`??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) then use one of the following alternatives:

- `node[prop] ||= {}`
- `(node[prop] = node[prop] ?? {})`
- `(node[prop] = node[prop] || {})`

### Some comments on your code

As this function builds the object from scratch, it is not really necessary to treat intermediate versions of the object as immutable -- as your code attempts to do at least in the case of `path.length == 0`: just keep extending the object through mutation.

`return o[s] = {};` is destructive: if the property was already created from a previously processed path, then this will overwrite whatever was already assigned to `o[s]`.

Comment: can you try with reduce same ?

Comment: Added a version with reduce.

Comment: And added another with a nested reduce.

Comment: What is. the use of. ?? ...  react. is. not allowing to. use that.. just. see. it. is. workinng after. using ??

Comment: It is the [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment). An assignment is needed though. In this case `||=` would also work. If that isn't supported either, then go for `(node[prop] = node[prop] ?? {})` or `(node[prop] = node[prop] || {})`

Comment: what is. the alternative for this ?

Comment: Added to my answer (see also updated comment above).